# How do I exit the help menu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythonanywhere

I am using PythonAnywhere to run 3.4, and when I use `help(math)` I get a menu. How do I exit the menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The help menu opens up in your default pager (usually `less`). Press <kbd>q</kbd> to quit it.